# How to count unique values sql for last few days?

Tags: sql-server, vertica, sql-function

I need to count distinct values in sql (Vertica) in a certain period of time. 
I have table like it: named U

```
+---------+--------------+---------+
| user_id | dt           | type_id |
+---------+--------------+---------+
| 1       | '2016-01-01' | 7       |
| 2       | '2016-01-01' | 7       |
| 3       | '2016-01-01' | 8       |
| 4       | '2016-01-03' | 7       |
| 3       | '2016-01-03' | 7       |
| 2       | '2016-01-03' | 8       |
| 1       | '2016-01-09' | 7       |
| 3       | '2016-01-09' | 7       |
| 5       | '2016-01-09' | 8       |
+---------+--------------+---------+
```

and code I think should be like

```
select (count(distinct(u.user_id)) over last 7 date(u.dt) ) as n_last_7_day, date(u.dt), u.type_id
from u 
group by date(u.dt), u.type_id
```

And the output I'm waiting for is like:

```
+--------------+--------------+---------+
| n_last_7_day |      dt      | type_id |
+--------------+--------------+---------+
|            4 | '2016-01-01' |       7 |
|            2 | '2016-01-01' |       8 |
|            3 | '2016-01-03' |       7 |
|            2 | '2016-01-03' |       8 |
|            2 | '2016-01-09' |       7 |
|            1 | '2016-01-09' |       8 |
+--------------+--------------+---------+
```

cause it was user 1, 2 in '2016-01-01' and plus 3 and 4 in '2016-01-03' less than 7 days so in the outpu we have number 4 for '2016-01-01' and type_id 7

Comment: sql-server <> vertica. They are completely different DBMS

Comment: Cross-posted: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/135930/how-to-count-unique-values-sql-for-last-few-days

Comment: done, but it still doesn't help